# Store sorted by primary key data in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Application works on test server and production server, both are integrated with Oracle 11g DB.

I noticed that there is some ordering on test server when storing data in table:

```
SELECT * FROM table1:
    |ID-PK| FK1 |name|
    | 100 | 50  | a1 |
    | 101 | 50  | a2 |
    | 102 | 50  | a3 |
```

When I'm performing the same query for the same table on another DB-server I got some unordered result:

```
SELECT * FROM table1:
    |ID-PK| FK1 |name|
    | 102 | 50  | a3 |
    | 100 | 50  | a1 |
    | 101 | 50  | a2 |
```

How I can force the second DB store data sorted by PK?

Inserted entities are created by Java web-application (with JPA), PK is generated with increment sequence, so the entities created later should be displayed in the end of table.

Comment: Use `order by` - that's the **only** (really: the *only*) way to get a defined order when selecting. There is no alternative

Comment: You already got the same (correct) answer twice, in an Answer and again in a Comment. The next question you should ask is, "then why do I get the rows in order in the first query? When can I rely on that?" The answer is, to the first question, "it doesn't matter" and to the second, "NEVER." Just take the first query result as a fluke; you may not even get the same behavior tomorrow. Try adding a row with PK=95 (if it is not used already) to see what happens!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data in a table is not stored in order. Without adding a `ORDER BY` to your query, the database will return the rows from the table the fastest way it can read them from disk / storage, which does not guarantee them being returned in a sorted order.

It's possible that the data that was returned by the query on the 1st server to already have been in the buffer cache, returned by a previously ran query which had an `ORDER BY`.

And when you issued your query, which is missing the `ORDER BY`, the engine decided to pull the data from the buffer cache instead of going back to disk, which is why they appear "in order".

Comment: Data in a table is always stored in *some* order (by ROWID perhaps?). The first query *may* just show the rows in the order they were inserted in the table, if the table never had any deletes or updates, and if the PK's were in increasing order. It's just that this physical ordering should never be relied on, there is absolutely no promise that rows will ever be displayed that way by any query, and even the physical order on disk may change over time. But it **is** possible the rows came out "sorted" straight from disk in Query 1.

Comment: @mathguy True, but what about virtualized storage? Anyway, the bottom line is, as you have also pointed out, no guarantee for data being returned "in order" without using a `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Of course. My only point with the comment was, "OK, but why does Query 1 actually show the rows sorted?" People get the wrong impression, from seeing that behavior - especially in a single user environment (like mine) and on a table with no transactions, the rows will always come in the order in which they were inserted. and now I may start getting ideas. Those ideas would be completely wrong, as we are all saying here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have data order when you directly query the table, you can use an IOT(index organized table), but this might have performance impacts depending on how wide your table is. The clean solution for heap tables is to use the ORDER BY clause.